# Unable to run phpdoc command after installing phpdoc/phpDocumentor package

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, phpdoc, php-7.2, phpdocumentor2

Although I followed the instruction to install phpDocumentor, Command line doesn't seem to respond to `phpdoc`

Given error: 
**Command 'phpdoc' not found, did you mean:
  command 'phploc' from deb phploc
  command 'phpdox' from deb phpdox
Try: sudo apt install**

I followed these steps to install phpdoc and it seemed to work

`pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org`

`pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor`

When the installation completed I tried to run phpdoc -h and it did not work.

Using: **7.2.16**

OS: **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**

*I appreciate any attempt to help.*

Comment: Could you check the section *Modifying php.ini* from the pear documentation and try to check if that works. https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Comment: Did you `sudo` those install commands? (Just curious, I just installed on Linux Mint 18.1 without problems) Did you try any of the other installation methods?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't look like the problem is with the installation @kerbholz

Comment: @JensV I actually added `include_path=".:/home/user/pear/share/pear"` manually. but it doesn't have anything to do with `phpdoc` am I right? beacouse `pear` already works.

Comment: What does `whereis phpdoc` return? Is that path in your `PATH`? (Mine says `phpdoc: /usr/bin/phpdoc`)

Comment: `phpdoc:` followed by nothing, can I add it manually?

Comment: It seems like it actually didn't get installed correctly. As kerbholz points out, there should be a binary there. Either `/usr/bin` isn't in your `$PATH` (check with `echo $PATH`) which is very unlikely, or something went wrong with the installation. Try to reinstall it, making sure you run it as root. Also pay attention to any potential error messages returned by pear.

Comment: Ok I'm trying it now

Comment: @JensV I tried it and it gave the message `install ok` as it's supposed to, but still no progress

Answer (score 1):

Check directories in your your path with

```
echo $PATH
```

phpdoc should be in /usr/bin. Check it with

```
ls -l /usr/bin/php*
```

If phpdoc is there, add exec perms with

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/phpdoc
```

But most likely he is not in the path, so go for a search

```
find . -name testfile.txt
```

When you have identified where phpdoc is, you must either add the folder where it is located to the PATH, or create a symbolic link (symln :

to this file in a directory of the PATH.

For PATH extension, do :

export PATH=$PATH:/my/custom/path

For a symlink, **cd** to a directory in your PATH. After that do

```
ln -s /my/custom/path/phpdoc
```

A good custom binary directory is /usr/local/bin.

You have to perform all this task as root or  with sudo.